# nfc tag compatibility with google nexus 5

Tags: nfc, tectiles

does anyone know if samsungs tec tile 2 (note the 2!) are compatible with the google nexus 5? in fact, does anyone have a list of compatible nfc tags?

(i thought the whole idea of nfc tags is that they are compatible, but it appears that the tectile 1's are compatible with even the newest samsung phones)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://nfctimes.com/news/samsung-expands-distribution-branded-tags-uses-standard-chip) Tectiles 2 tags are based on the NFC Forum Type 4 tag standard (though the article does not mention an exact chip). Also Samsung explicitly released Tectiles 2 for use with devices that have non-NXP NFC chipsets (like Galaxy S4). This means that these tags are compatible to all current Android NFC devices including the Nexus 5.